# Hitting control button ejects DVD drive

Tags: dvd, drive, eject

I have upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04. Everything is fine so far. But every time I press left control button, my DVD drive ejects. It does not happen with right control button. I have searched for answers but could not find anything. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you run `gsettings list-recursively 2> /dev/null | grep --ignore-case ctrl` and paste the output to http://paste.ubuntu.com/

Comment: I have pasted the list. http://paste.ubuntu.com/9489857/

Comment: So it's not in Gnome that the key was re-defined...  :-( Can you do a `xev | grep -A2 --line-buffered '^KeyRelease' | sed -n '/keycode /s/^.*keycode \([0-9]*\).* (.*, \(.*\)).*$/\1 \2/p'` and see whether the output gives you `9 Escape` 3 times if you press it 3 times?

Comment: 36 Return
9 Escape
9 Escape
9 Escape
This is the output I got.

Comment: Sorry, I was working on 2 keyboard problems at the same time and the last output was not for you... (copy-paste error from my side: the other user had an escape-key problem, you should have pressed the [Ctrl] key).  From the first output, I can see that the problem is deeper then gnome/unity, so could you post the output for [Ctrl] for `xev`?

Comment: 37 Control_L
37 Control_L
37 Control_L
This is the output. Hey I just wanted to thank you for looking at my issue.

Comment: yeah, but you're not going to like what I'm saying next: it's correct in Gnome, correct in X, so I have no clue where it was re-defined...  This happens not only in one particular application, does it???

Comment: No matter what application I am running. The moment I hit left control button, the drive ejects.

Comment: Grasping at straws now: `gsettings list-recursively  | grep --ignore-case "eject"`

Comment: org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys eject 'Control_L'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys eject 'Control_L'
org.gnome.desktop.a11y.keyboard bouncekeys-beep-reject false
org.gnome.desktop.a11y.keyboard slowkeys-beep-reject false

Comment: In system settings, I reassigned shortcut for the eject. The problem is solved. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final answer: In system settings, reassign the short-cut for the eject to anything not containing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>

Comment: Please click on the little grey check-mark icon below the "0" and that is the best "Thank you" you can give me as anyone else having this problem can find that as an accepted answer. (and my reputation goes up)  ;-)

Answer (score -2):

I don't have this problem but I may help you at least with a few ideas. First, I have Ubuntu installed on an old Windows laptop and as you may know the SUPER key showed in keyboard shortcuts is Windows key on my laptop. Now you may have a problem that Ubuntu will see your left CTRL as a key combo or a special key,so try to connect a different keyboard to see of it still does that. If yes, the key mapping has been understood wrong by Ubuntu  and you will have to search and download a keyboard mapping program, but the preliminary test for this is to put up the (or a) on-screen keyboard and see if clicking the LCTRL will still open your CD-ROM. In the ABSOLUTE worst case re-install Ubuntu.
Now I just found out: go to system settings, under Text Entry and in the bottom right corner you should see keyboard settings. Check that out. If nothing indicates the use of LCTRL then do sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool in terminal and from there you HAVE to find it. Thanks for reading!!

Comment: @Rares Thank You. I reassigned the eject shortcut and it is solved now! Left CTRL no more ejects the drive.